# How to display date in RDLC in another language

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I want to display date in RDLC(Report Definition Language Client-side) as `१०/०७/२०१०` instead 10/07/2010. How can i do this?

Comment: Is this date data or input parameter?

Comment: @ChiragVidani input paramerter

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible - at least not without effort on your side. Native digits are defined in .NET FW like:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("km-KH");
for (var i = 0; i < culture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits.Length; i++) {
     Console.Out.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits[i]);
}
```

BUT native digits formatting is not supported (yet).

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.digitsubstitution.aspx

> The DigitSubstitution property is reserved for future use. Currently,
>   it is not used in either parsing or formatting operations for the
>   current NumberFormatInfo object.

You still can manage to do it on your own - i.e. add Report->Report properties->Code

```
Function Khmer(value)
  value = Replace(value,"0","០")
  value = Replace(value,"1","១")
  value = Replace(value,"2","២")
  value = Replace(value,"3","៣")
  value = Replace(value,"4","៤")
  value = Replace(value,"5","៥")
  value = Replace(value,"6","៦")
  value = Replace(value,"7","៧")
  value = Replace(value,"8","៨")
  value = Replace(value,"9","៩")
  Khmer =  value
End Function
```

Note - report code uses vb syntax (always) - dunno why.
And in your report add expression for the field you want to encode to Khmer native digits:

```
=Code.Khmer(Fields!DateCreated.Value)
```